# Class 'Permissions' not found in rollback migrate laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, migrate

I have migrate like this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('permissions', function ($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->tinyInteger('value');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('techniciansgroup_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('techniciansgroup_id')->references('id')->on('techniciansgroups')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('permissions');
}
```

When i use this command

```
php artisan migrate
```

The database create correctly
but when i use rollback command

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

show this error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'Permissions' not found

Comment: Did you try to change anything in the DB or changed the files after running the migration?

Comment: No i am not. when i create database with migrate work correctly but when i rollback the database error not class found show me

Comment: Do you have any `model` for this table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I delete the permissions migrate and delete database.
after that I make permissions migration and use `php artisan migrate` and finally

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

work correctly.

Comment: This is not a solution to the issue, it's a brute force way to bring the functionality. The answer should highlight the reason for this issue, in addition to proposing a solution. Deleting the DB is never a solution, especially for a production DB.